# No EXCEL, Como usar Formatação em negrito de uma célula e aplicar em uma função "concatenar" em outra célula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho uma pequena tabela, pretendo usar a formatação em negrito da célula "A20" do numero '2001-T' e aplicar na função "concatenar" da célula "F20", porém qualquer tipo de formatação que eu faça na célula "A20" não se aplica também na célula "F20" junto com a função "concatenar" usada, como eu faço para aplicar a mesma formatação usada na célula "A20" ?? no numero '2001-T' da célula "F20" ??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Não tem como aplicar formato numa fórmula ou copiar o conteúdo com formatação.

`CONCATENAR` copia somente o texto. Se fosse uma formatação de número ou data, você podeira usar a função `TEXTO`, que pode aplicar um formato (por exemplo `=TEXTO(HOJE();"DD/MM/AA")`), mas não negrito, itálico e bordas por exemplo.

Para fazer esse tipo de formatação, precisa criar uma função em VBA, infelizmente é o único jeito.