# Como inserir formatação em cores através de uma fórmula no Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho duas células com caracteres com formatos de cores diferentes, porém ao usar a função `Concatenar` e outras funções para extrair os caracteres em outra célula, o formato de cores não se aplica conforme está definido nas duas células, como aplicar as mesmas cores na célula que foi utilizado na fórmula:

```
=CONCATENAR(ARRUMAR(DIREITA(ESQUERDA(SUBSTITUIR(ARRUMAR(E122);" ";REPT(" ";10));20);50));" ";D122)
```

[image]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [No EXCEL, Como usar Formatação em negrito de uma célula e aplicar em uma função "concatenar" em outra célula](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/335597/no-excel-como-usar-formata%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-negrito-de-uma-c%c3%a9lula-e-aplicar-em-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: Eu vou remover a pergunta

Comment: Incrivel não ter uma opção para aplicar cores em caracteres extraídos

Comment: Não precisa deletar, é bom que tenha várias perguntas de formas diferentes que direcionem para a mesma resposta. Ela precisa ser marcada como duplicata.